# Else if portion of my conditional is not returning

Tags: javascript

MY conditional is supposed to show any videos a user has created other it should return a prompt to create a video. The if portion is working for users that have videos however my else if portion does not return for users that do not have videos. What am I missing?

```js
const UserPage = props => {
  const { username } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    props.getUserVideos(localStorage.getItem("token"), username);
  }, [username]);

  let greeting;

  if (localStorage.getItem("username") === username) {
    greeting = `Welcome ${username}`;
    console.log("Welcome");
  } else {
    greeting = `${username} Videos`;
    console.log(username);
  }
  //this if statement will greet a user with a list of their videos, otherwise it will send a prompt to create a video

  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <h1>{greeting}</h1>
        <div style={videoListContainer}>
          <div style={VideoThumbsContainer}>
            {props.userVideos && props.userVideos ? (
              props.userVideos.map(video => {
                return (
                  <div key={video.id}>
                    <h3>{video.video_title}</h3>
                    <Link to={`/videos/${video.id}`}>
                      <Thumbnail video={video} />
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                );
              })
            ) : (
                <p>
                  Looks like you haven't created any videos yet, lets {""}
                  <Link to="/create">create some videos!</Link>
                </p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userVideos: state.userVideos,
  getUserVideosStart: state.getUserVideosStart,
  getUserVideosSuccess: state.getUserVideosSuccess,
  getUserVideosError: state.getUserVideosError
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getUserVideos }
)(withRouter(UserPage));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like an odd condition:

```
props.userVideos && props.userVideos
```

You're checking the same thing twice.  At no point would one of these be "truthy" and the other one not.  Perhaps you meant to check the *length* of the array?:

```
props.userVideos && props.userVideos.length > 0
```

Otherwise the only way to trigger the `else` condition here would be for `userVideos` to be `null` or `undefined`.  If `props.userVideos` is an empty array then simply checking `if (props.userVideos)` would still be `true`.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick, thank you. So by adding " > 0" that is giving it a "falsy" portion of the conditional correct? However, I don't fully understand how .length works in these situations. From what I've understood about .length is it returns a number of characters in a string or the total number of items in an array.

Comment: @GPLP: And isn't the number of items in an array exactly what you want to test here?

Comment: ahhhhhhh yes I absolutely am, again thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have your logic backwards:

```
localStorage.getItem("username") === username
```

that sounds like "existing users" logic, but in your code it goes to "welcome" message.

my guess is the way you have your data structured, getItem("username") will never equal username

Comment: It returns the "Welcome" greeting regardless of being an existing user or not. The "if" portion is returning fine with the greeting and then a list of videos for users that have created videos.

Comment: right. because getItem("username") will never equal username. they are not of the same data types.

Comment: try adding this: console.log(localStorage.getItem("username"), username);

Comment: I think you looking at the wrong conditional. That one is working just fine the string of username is equal to username so that when a user logs in they are greeted by "Welcome (whatever your username is in the form of a string)". The one I was stuck on was below that for the userVideos to show the list of videos if they had created any. Otherwise it should send a prompt of "Looks like you haven't created any videos yet, lets create some videos!"